# Is this proof wrong?

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, alternative-set-theories

I am reading Decio Krause's quasi set theory (2010).

It allows ZF axiomatic set theory to exist within it but with a couple new fundamentals.

One of the theorems had a proof which I can't make sense of.

The following definitions and axioms are to understand the proof.

Definitions:
$Q(x)\iff x\text{ is a quasi-set (qset)}$
$D(x)\iff x\text{ is a classical thing}$
$Z(x)\iff x\text{ is a [ZF] set}$
$\forall_Qx$ is universal quantification relative to qsets
$\exists_Qx$ is existential quantification relative to qsets

**Axiom 8: Qsets Whose Elements Are Classical Things Are Sets and Conversely**
$$\forall_Qx(\forall y(y\in x\implies D(y))\iff Z(x))$$

**Axiom 10: The Empty Qset**
$$\exists_Qx\forall y(\neg(y\in x))$$
Let $x_{A10}:=\emptyset$

**Theorem 7: The Empty Qset is a set**

It is left as a theorem that the empty quasi set is a [ZF] set.

**PROOF**:
(from the text)

"Since $y\in x$ is false by A10, then the antecedent of $\forall y(y\in x\implies D(y))$ is true, hence $Z(\emptyset)$ by A8"

**CONFUSION**

If $y\in x$ is false, and $y\in x$  is the antecedent, then how the antecedent be true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Axiom A8 applied to $\emptyset$ is: $\forall y(y \in \emptyset \to D(y)) \leftrightarrow Z(\emptyset)$, from which:

> $\forall y(y \in \emptyset \to D(y)) \to Z(\emptyset)$,

using [Biconditional elimination rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconditional_elimination).

From axiom A10 we have: $∀y(¬(y \in \emptyset))$ and thus:

1. $¬(y \in \emptyset)$ --- from A10 by [UI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation)
2. $¬(y \in \emptyset) \to [(y \in \emptyset) \to D(y)]$ --- using [tautology $\lnot P \to (P \to Q))$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion#Symbolic_representation)
3. $(y \in \emptyset) \to D(y))$ --- from 1) and 2) by [Modus Ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens)
4. $\forall y ((y \in \emptyset) \to D(y))$ --- from 3) by [UG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization)

> 5. $Z(\emptyset)$ --- from A8 and 4) by Modus Ponens.

Comment: I seriously need to brush up on my propositional logic but I am lost. Sorry . I am confused on both how you got to ~P→(P→Q) and how that would imply Z(∅).

Comment: Yes, thank you. It's been a big help.))

Comment: @IsaacSechslingloff - you are welcome :-)